# Changing alignment in derived type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, thrust, memory-alignment

Say you have these two types:

```
struct alignas(8) Base { double a; double b; }
struct alignas(16) Derived : public Base {}
```

And these functions:

```
void Foo(Base b)
void Bar(Base* start, Base* end)
```

Is it legal to make calls like

```
Foo(someDerived)
Bar(someDerivedArray, someDerivedArray + arrayLength)
```

in all cases? Does it depend on the contents of `Base` and the specific alignment restrictions? I could absolutely see there being an issue if `derived` were, say, 32-bit aligned, because then there'd be a gap in-between elements of `someDerivedArray` and `Bar` wouldn't know about that gap, so I assume this is undefined behaviour, but I'm not sure.

XY explanation: we're using the GPGPU library Thrust and its complex type has inconsistent alignments between device code and host code; we're trying to figure out how to work around the issue. One option is to define our own complex type deriving from `thrust::complex` but with the same alignment specifier and use that, but of course various thrust functions expect a `thrust::complex`, so we'd be slicing into or casting into the less-aligned type.

Comment: The second function obviously doesn't make sense, regardless of alignment. It's *not* an array of `Base` and doing pointer arithmetic on it is UB. It's like doing `std::pair<int, double> p[5]; std::for_each(&p.i, &p[4].i, [](auto& i){ i++; });`

Comment: Also, `Foo(someDerived)` will copy-construct a new Base from `someDerived`. Perhaps you meant `Foo(const Base&)`for your first example function?

Comment: @Frank no, some functions take a `thrust::complex` by value.

Comment: @PasserBy Good point.

Comment: @JamesPicone What I mean is that since a brand new object of the exact type the function expects is created at the callsite, alignment concerns do not come into play, making the question moot.

Comment: Can't you simply use `std::aligned_alloc` and a placement new to allocate the `thrust::complex` array in the client with the host's alignment requirement?

Comment: @Frank In actual use the object is buried in a vector in a map in a struct etc. etc.; changing the thrust headers to fix their bug is probably easier than getting custom allocators all the way down. EDIT: Also `std::aligned_alloc` isn't in MSVC which is our target compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Doing pointer arithmetic on a `Base*`, if the pointer actually points to a `Derived` object, it always UB. Alignment is irrelevant. If `Base` and `Derived` have the same *size* then this might appear to work, but it is still UB.

Passing a pointer to a `Derived` object to a function that takes `Base*`, and does *not* perform pointer arithmetic, is usually fine, with the caveat that if the function will be performing `delete` on the pointer, then `Base` must have a virtual destructor. Again, alignment is not relevant.

The reason why increasing the alignment of `Derived` makes no difference is that the `Base` subobject of it is still forced to be aligned according to the alignment of `Base`. (This is why, in general, you can increase the alignment of a derived class relative to the base class, but not decrease.) So when the `Derived*` is converted to a `Base*`, you still get a valid pointer value: it points to a `Base` object and that object is correctly aligned. (In fact, there is no such thing as an object that is not properly aligned for its type. Any attempt to create such an object would cause UB.)

So `Foo(someDerived)` will usually be fine as long as `Foo` doesn't attempt to `delete` the pointer, whereas `Bar(someDerivedArray, someDerivedArray + arrayLength)` will not.

Answer (score -3):

`alignas` applies only to Base and Derived;
They do not apply to their members: `a` and `b`.

So there are no issues.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int x, y, z, w;
};

struct alignas(64) B
{
    alignas(64) int x;
    alignas(64) float y, z, w;
};

struct alignas(64) C : public A
{
};

int main()
{
A a;
B b;
C c;
cout << size_t((char*)(void*)&(a.y)-(char*)(void*)&(a.x)) << endl;
cout << size_t((char*)(void*)&(b.y)-(char*)(void*)&(b.x)) << endl;
cout << size_t((char*)(void*)&(c.y)-(char*)(void*)&(c.x)) << endl;  
return 0;
}
```

It returns

```
4
64
4
```

**Edit**: if you don't believe me, run the code yourself. I am not sure why would anyone think that `alignas` would enforce alignment to each member of the class.
The definition of `alignas` states that it applies to the class itself (only that the alignment of the class is affected by alignment of its members and not members affected by the class).

**Edit 2**: with regards to Thrust - if device and host decide on different alignments in classes then it is an error of consistency of different compilers that need to be in sync. You can file the bug to NVIDIA as it is their problem.

How to workaround such problems? That's a complicated question... good luck.

Comment: I am concerned about the alignment of `Base` and `Derived`, not the alignment of their components. And yes, it's clearly a thrust bug, and we are filing a bug with NVIDIA, but thrust seems to be updated very slowly so a workaround is what we're looking for for now. We're hoping to avoid having to modify the thrust headers.

Comment: Derived is informed about alignment and size of Base - so there cannot be issues on this front. Think of Base as a member of Derived in this context. It works a bit different for virtual inheritance tho. Like some commenters above said there are no alignment issues in the functions you described. Only that `Bar(Derived,Derived)` won't work as it doesn't know/use size of the Derived class.

Comment: Well there clearly can be issues when a function is expecting pointers into an array of `Base`, as a user noted in a comment on the question. The problem isn't whether or not `Derived` is sensible. The problem is in what contexts a `Derived` (or some related type like `Derived&`) cannot legally be passed to something expecting a `Base` (or some related type like `Base&`).

Comment: As long as Derived publicly inherits Base, you can freely cast `Derived` to whatever `Base`: `Base`, `Base&`, `Base*` - it all works without issues.

Comment: I am not familiar with Thrust, but normally one shouldn't send anything more complicated than simple structures into the GPU device. When working with GPUs, it is frequent that code compiles but causes run-time errors because it doesn't follow requirements. E.g., in SYCL you can pass any lambda to the GPU to execute but if you pass any references or use any external pointers - it will cause a run-time error.